# Meaning of 拝む in the following sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs, manga

Context: after winning a match, a boxer goes at the hospital to visit the opponent he defeated, but there he finds the loser's girlfriend too. The boy tries to ask how his opponent is doing, at which the girl replies that he can have a look at his face if he wants, and then adds:

> 敗者をどういじるも勝者の特権。これから自分下した勝者【あいて】を忘れよーとしながらも背負ってく　…この顔**拝む**なら今しかないよ

Is 拝む being used with the meaning of `to pay one's respects` or `to see`? I think she's being sarcastic, but I am not sure. My transation attempt:

> Choosing how to treat the defeated is a special privilege of the winner. From now on, even if he will try to forget the one that defeated him, it will still be a burden for him. This is the only time you can see(?) his face.

I uploaded [the whole page and the following one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXUjH.jpg) to provide more context. It would be great if you could also check the rest of my translation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `the ones you defeat` -- 「自分下した[勝者]{あいて}」 means "the one(s) who defeated you", right? (≂「自分**を**下したあいて」, not 「自分**が**下したあいて」.. cos it's 勝者, not 敗者.) 「これから自分下した勝者を忘れよーとしながらも背負ってく...」 describes この顔.

Comment: Thank you @Chocolate! I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel this 拝む is closer to "to enjoy/appreciate", rather than "to pay respect" or "to worship".

> #### [拝む](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/29998/meaning/m0u/%E6%8B%9D%E3%82%80/)
>
> ２ 「見る」の謙譲語。お目にかかる。また、珍しい物、大事な物などを拝見・拝観する。「お顔を―・みに伺います」「秘宝を―・ませていただいた」「彼女の顔を―・みたい」

This is a bit comical word choice, and she's comparing his face to some famous tourist attraction, but 拝む in this sentence no longer carries religious implication. This 
拝む refers to what ordinary tourists who are not particularly religious do in front of a Buddhist statue in Kyoto. "Oh this is the famous ...!"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you also please provide some information about いじる in this case? I translated it as "to treat", is it closer to "to harass" instead?

Comment: You can leave it as "to treat". She says the winner can choose to harass, not to harass, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I think your translation is almost correct. *This is the only time you can see(?) his face.* is a subtle part. It seems to me この顔拝むなら今しかないよ refers to the showing a respect for the loser since the protagonist felt the game was able to be well-founded thanks to the existence of the opponent and his grit.